# Catching Sqlite commandline function error in C

Tags: c, sqlite

I have inserts.txt file which contains some "INSERT ..." commands and an empty Sqlite3 database.
I typed this command in commanline:

```
sqlite3 database.db '.read inserts.txt'
```

after that my database was populated.

But if there are some wrong queries in txt file I get some errors like

```
Error: no such table: asdsa
```

I use sqlite commands in a C code. How can I catch this error in C code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing a C program using sqlite3 C API, use the [`sqlite3_errmsg()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) to get a human-readable error message.

Otherwise please clarify your question.

Comment: He's asking about the command line program. (He shouldn't do it that way, but that's what he's asking about.)